# Where should I farm enemies in Snowdin?

Tags: undertale

Say I'm speedrunning Undertale. This usually means you're doing a genocide run, and need to kill a certain number of enemies per section.

Snowdin in particular seems difficult to get the right number of enemies to spawn.

- In the Ruins, you can run circles in the room right under the candy.
- Hotland is quite easy to get the right number of kills just by taking the usual path.
- The Core has the final bridge before the Mettaton fight.

I can't figure out Snowdin. Where should I walk to maximize the number of encounters?

Comment: If you press up+down at the same time, you'll move back and forth very rapidly

Comment: Yup, but it's definitely appears to be location based in the runs I've done. The core, you seem to get a lot more encounters on the final bridge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best spot to grind encounters in Snowdin is on the last screen before reaching Snowdin town. This way, you minimize the amount of "but nobody came" encounters throughout Snowdin. This is based on current WR strats.

Entering Snowdin Town and then immediately going back to grinding also appears to be a time save, since the WR, 2nd place, and 3rd place runs do this. This is likely because encounters are based on step count and RNG, and your step count resets when you enter a room.

Answer (score 2):

I had a bit of trouble with this part too in the genocide run, but the most frequent ones are the ones that aren't near papyrus's puzzles and save points. But, the place I recommend you go to and farm is right before the "spaghetti trap."

Answer (score 1):

[image: Most encounters here]

I got the most encounters in this area. Last time I tried to grind at the end of Snowdin Forest, it ruined my genocide run.

Comment: Plus, there's a SAVE point, so you don't have to worry about losing too much HP.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

this is where i get the most (and easiest) encounters
just do up+down here

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can farm anywhere, except for the places where Papyrus's puzzles are and savepoint places. The easiest way to farm is to hold an arrow button and click out of the game window as it puts the character in a static position where it triggers an autorun animation. If you don't know. But watch out after doing that. Your character might be stuck in a static animation while you walk again and stop walking which will supposedly to stop it. Or when the attack box is there, one of the arrow keys might be stuck unless you start moving around quick first.

Comment: I think the OP asked specifically for the best spot. And judging from the other answers, there are spots that are better or worse.

Answer (score -1):

I Recommend The Map Near The "Warning: Dog Marriage" Sign. Do The Up + Down Feature And Keep Doing It.

Good Luck.

Answer (score -2):

If your looking for monsters don't go to tooms you have already had 3 encounters as there are only 3 per room