# How/where to find the last monsters in Snowdin on a genocide run?

Tags: undertale

I'm on a genocide run, and I have been searching everywhere to find the last encounter in Snowdin. What is the best place/way to search for it?

[image]

Comment: I'm flagging this because I think that this question is way to vague. It doesn't say what monster you need to find, what you tried to do, or what version it's in. Can you try making this more descriptive?

Comment: [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/264321/20456) might be useful for you.

Comment: I think that this question simply asks for a list of monsters in Snowdin, I haven't played undertale, so I'm not sure, but I think that a list like that likely isn't too broad. I also don't think that it is a duplicate, as the other question only asks for random encounters and how to be the most efficient. I may be wrong, I don't know, I will skip this question in the review queue.

Answer (score 1):

In the Genocide route, monsters are essentially random spawns.
You're either just unlucky or impatient. Just keep on walking around until something spawns.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to walk around in the room where you fight Dogamy and Dogaressa. took quite a while though.